# TowelRoot for rooting android devices - does it work?

Tags: android, root

I tried to root my Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android version 4.1.2 using TowelRoot's APK which I installed on the device, but it didn't work.

I looked inside he APK and saw that it connects to the TowelRoot's server and sends to it the details about the device. Somehow, the server always returns that the device is not supported.

Does TowelRoot is not supported anymore? Is there a different exploit that I can use that might work for Samsung Galaxy S3 and newer devices (it might be based on TowelRoot's vulnerability and might be not based on it)?

Comment: This is not the correct place to ask this, ask in android.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may need to ask a higher quality question on the Android SE, just a heads up.

Comment: Please copy and paste your question into Notepad, then click "delete", then repost it on Android.SE.  (Why use Notepad?  Because, on Stack Exchange, "delete" is sometimes an undoable operation but sometimes not.  I speak from experience.)